# Python Multiprocessing get slower and slower. Why?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing code like this.

```
from mulitprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(8)

pooled_result = pool.map(my_function, my_list)
```

For each iteration it takes 3~4 secs at beginning.
However, it takes longer time for each iteration as time goes.

At last, it takes almost 60 secs for each iteration. I don't know the reason.

Moreover, in my terminal(mac) the 8 process looks clearly. The line is exactly 8. (Please check my comments)

However, if I copy and paste my code into Google Colab, the executing line looks weird. There are not 8 lines. The lines are appended continuously for each iteration.

Comment: In my terminal, 1000it [1:50:12, 5.29s/it]
    1004it [1:50:13, 4.52s/it]
    1002it [1:50:12, 5.24s/it]
    1010it [1:50:13, 5.19s/it]
    1004it [1:50:13, 5.69s/it]
    1006it [1:50:14, 7.39s/it]
    1004it [1:50:17, 5.20s/it]
    1003it [1:50:15, 5.29s/it]

Comment: But in my google colab, 1it [00:06,  6.82s/it]
1it [00:07,  7.11s/it]
2it [00:08,  5.33s/it]






1it [00:08,  8.45s/it]





1it [00:08,  8.72s/it]






2it [00:08,  6.04s/it]


1it [00:09,  9.23s/it]




1it [00:09,  9.29s/it]



1it [00:10, 10.65s/it]


2it [00:18,  9.12s/it]

2it [00:18,  8.31s/it]
3it [00:18,  6.89s/it]




2it [00:19,  9.69s/it]





2it [00:19,  9.48s/it]






3it [00:20,  7.59s/it]



1it [00:27, 27.62s/it]

3it [00:28,  9.33s/it]
4it [00:29,  7.89s/it]
3it [00:29,  9.20s/it]
3it [00:30, 10.15s/it]